# Grafico circular elementos nietos repetidos no se muestran

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando un gráfico con la librería [Plot.ly](https://plot.ly/javascript/) de tipo [Sunburst](https://plot.ly/javascript/sunburst-charts/) y tengo un problema que no logro resolver, el gráfico tiene tres tipos de elementos:

- Padres
- Hijos
- Nietos

Entre padres e hijos no existe ningún conflicto, pero los nietos es otra cosa, los hijos están asignados a un padre y son únicos, pero los nietos pueden estar asignados a varios padres y repetirse varias veces por padre, entonces, al mostrarse solo aparecen una vez en un padre en vez de los varios a los que está asignado, otro problema es que cada nieto se puede repetir `n` veces, que representa el porcentaje de ocupación del padre, para esto tengo solución pero sin solucionar el primer problema es imposible aplicarlo.

Dejo un [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrLc094y/9/) con el gráfico actual.

```js
var obj = [{Id:null,Padre:"",Nombre:null},{Id:"246L",Padre:"",Nombre:"MEG"},{Id:"234L",Padre:"",Nombre:"KNIFE DRIVE"},{Id:"247P",Padre:"234L",Nombre:"MONTAJE GEN II"},{Id:"248P",Padre:"234L",Nombre:"PREMONTAJES GEN II"},{Id:"366P",Padre:"246L",Nombre:"MONTAJE FINAL"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82511",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32198"},{Id:"82511",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32198"},{Id:"82511",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32198"},{Id:"82511",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32198"},{Id:"82511",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32198"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},{Id:"82511",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32198"},{Id:"82511",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32198"},{Id:"82511",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32198"},{Id:"83552",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32235"},{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"}];

//VARIABLES
var ids = [];
var nombres = [];
var padres = [];
var colores = [];
var nLineas = 0;

//FUNCIONES
function rgba2hex(orig) {
  var a, isPercent,
      rgb = orig.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/^rgba?\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),?([^,\s)]+)?/i),
      alpha = (rgb && rgb[4] || "").trim(),
      hex = rgb ?
      (rgb[1] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
      (rgb[2] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
      (rgb[3] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) : orig;

  if (alpha !== "") {
    a = alpha;
  } else {
    a = 01;
  }
  // multiply before convert to HEX
  a = ((a * 255) | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1)
  hex = hex + a;

  return hex;
}

function random_rgba() {
  var o = Math.round, r = Math.random, s = 255;
  return 'rgba(' + o(r() * s) + ',' + o(r() * s) + ',' + o(r() * s) + ',' + 0.7 + ')';
}

function SplitDatos(datos) {
  
  $.each(datos, function (index, value) {
    ids.push(value.Id);
    padres.push(value.Padre);
    nombres.push(value.Nombre);    
  });

}

$(document).ready(function(){

  SplitDatos(obj);

  var data = [{
    type: "sunburst",
    ids: ids,
    labels: nombres,
    parents: padres,
    outsidetextfont: { size: 20, color: "#377eb8" },
    textposition: 'inside',
    insidetextorientation: 'tangential',
    // leaf: {opacity: 0.4},
    marker: { line: { width: 2 } },
  }];

  for (var i = 0; i < nLineas; i++) {
    var colorRGB = random_rgba();
    colores.push(rgba2hex(colorRGB));
  }

  var layout = {
    margin: { l: 0, r: 0, b: 0, t: 0 },
    sunburstcolorway: colores,
  };

  //console.log("Pinto el circulo");
  Plotly.newPlot('Pie', data, layout);    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='Pie'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
```

Comment: Según veo como lo planteas, quizá lo más apropiado sea repetir los nietos, y que se diferencien en que hijo tienen asignado...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te falla porque tienes elementos repetidos y en lugar de ignorarlos completamente, los usa para calcular el ancho: si tienes 10 veces un elemento, aparecerá una vez pero con 1/10 de la anchura que debería:

```js
var obj = [
  {Id:null,Padre:"",Nombre:null},{Id:"246L",Padre:"",Nombre:"MEG"},
  {Id:"234L",Padre:"",Nombre:"KNIFE DRIVE"},{Id:"247P",Padre:"234L",Nombre:"MONTAJE GEN II"},
  {Id:"248P",Padre:"234L",Nombre:"PREMONTAJES GEN II"},
  {Id:"366P",Padre:"246L",Nombre:"MONTAJE FINAL"},
  {Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
  {Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
  {Id:"82511",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32198"},
  {Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
  {Id:"83552",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32235"},
  {Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"}];

//VARIABLES
var ids = [];
var nombres = [];
var padres = [];
var colores = [];
var nLineas = 0;

//FUNCIONES
function rgba2hex(orig) {
  var a, isPercent,
      rgb = orig.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/^rgba?\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),?([^,\s)]+)?/i),
      alpha = (rgb && rgb[4] || "").trim(),
      hex = rgb ?
      (rgb[1] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
      (rgb[2] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
      (rgb[3] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) : orig;

  if (alpha !== "") {
    a = alpha;
  } else {
    a = 01;
  }
  // multiply before convert to HEX
  a = ((a * 255) | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1)
  hex = hex + a;

  return hex;
}

function random_rgba() {
  var o = Math.round, r = Math.random, s = 255;
  return 'rgba(' + o(r() * s) + ',' + o(r() * s) + ',' + o(r() * s) + ',' + 0.7 + ')';
}

function SplitDatos(datos) {
  
  $.each(datos, function (index, value) {
    ids.push(value.Id);
    padres.push(value.Padre);
    nombres.push(value.Nombre);    
  });

}

$(document).ready(function(){

  SplitDatos(obj);

  var data = [{
    type: "sunburst",
    ids: ids,
    labels: nombres,
    parents: padres,
    outsidetextfont: { size: 20, color: "#377eb8" },
    textposition: 'inside',
    insidetextorientation: 'tangential',
    // leaf: {opacity: 0.4},
    marker: { line: { width: 2 } },
  }];

  for (var i = 0; i < nLineas; i++) {
    var colorRGB = random_rgba();
    colores.push(rgba2hex(colorRGB));
  }

  var layout = {
    margin: { l: 0, r: 0, b: 0, t: 0 },
    sunburstcolorway: colores,
  };

  //console.log("Pinto el circulo");
  Plotly.newPlot('Pie', data, layout);    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='Pie'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
```

Una solución es agrupar los repetidos y añadir el número de repeticiones como valor en el gráfico:

```js
var obj = [
{Id:null,Padre:"",Nombre:null},
{Id:"246L",Padre:"",Nombre:"MEG"},
{Id:"234L",Padre:"",Nombre:"KNIFE DRIVE"},
{Id:"247P",Padre:"234L",Nombre:"MONTAJE GEN II"},
{Id:"248P",Padre:"234L",Nombre:"PREMONTAJES GEN II"},
{Id:"366P",Padre:"246L",Nombre:"MONTAJE FINAL"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82511",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32198"},
{Id:"82511",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32198"},
{Id:"82511",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32198"},
{Id:"82511",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32198"},
{Id:"82511",Padre:"247P",Nombre:"DE32198"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"50132",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE21086"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82510",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32087"},
{Id:"82511",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32198"},
{Id:"82511",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32198"},
{Id:"82511",Padre:"248P",Nombre:"DE32198"},
{Id:"83552",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32235"},
{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},
{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},
{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},
{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},
{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},
{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},
{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},
{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"},
{Id:"83553",Padre:"366P",Nombre:"DE32333"}];

let count = {};
obj = obj.filter(elem => {
  if (count[elem.Id] === undefined) {
    count[elem.Id]=1;
    return true;
  } else {
    count[elem.Id]++;
    return false;
  }
});

obj.forEach(elem => elem.Repetido = count[elem.Id]);

function unpack(rows, key) {
  return rows.map(function(row) { return row[key]; });
}





//VARIABLES
var colores = [];
var nLineas = 0;

//FUNCIONES
function rgba2hex(orig) {
  var a, isPercent,
      rgb = orig.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/^rgba?\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),?([^,\s)]+)?/i),
      alpha = (rgb && rgb[4] || "").trim(),
      hex = rgb ?
      (rgb[1] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
      (rgb[2] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
      (rgb[3] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) : orig;

  if (alpha !== "") {
    a = alpha;
  } else {
    a = 01;
  }
  // multiply before convert to HEX
  a = ((a * 255) | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1)
  hex = hex + a;

  return hex;
}

function random_rgba() {
  var o = Math.round, r = Math.random, s = 255;
  return 'rgba(' + o(r() * s) + ',' + o(r() * s) + ',' + o(r() * s) + ',' + 0.7 + ')';
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  var data = [{
    type: "sunburst",
    ids: unpack(obj,'Id'),
    labels: unpack(obj,'Nombre'),
    parents: unpack(obj,'Padre'),
    values: unpack(obj,'Repetido'),
    outsidetextfont: { size: 20, color: "#377eb8" },
    textposition: 'inside',
    insidetextorientation: 'tangential',
    
    marker: { line: { width: 2 } }
  }];

  for (var i = 0; i < nLineas; i++) {
    var colorRGB = random_rgba();
    colores.push(rgba2hex(colorRGB));
  }

  var layout = {
    margin: { l: 0, r: 0, b: 0, t: 0 },
    sunburstcolorway: colores,
  };

  //console.log("Pinto el circulo");
  Plotly.newPlot('Pie', data, layout);    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='Pie'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
```